# Derivative of $\cos(x)^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

I'm trying to find the derivative of 
$$f(x) = \cos(x)^{1/x}.$$

Would it be a good idea to see it as a composition of functions to use the chain rule? Not seeing a clear path to a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left((\cos{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)'=\left(e^{\frac{\ln\cos{x}}{x}}\right)'=e^{\frac{\ln\cos{x}}{x}}\left(\frac{\ln\cos{x}}{x}\right)'=(\cos{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(-\frac{\sin{x}}{x\cos{x}}-\frac{\ln\cos{x}}{x^2}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain how do you rewrote that function in terms of exponential function?

Comment: @F. Zer I used a definition of $\ln$: $e^{\ln{x}}=x$ and $\ln(\cos{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{x}\ln\cos{x}.$

Answer (score 3):

Let $$y=\cos(x)^{1/x}$$ so $$\ln(y)=\frac{1}{x}\ln(\cos(x))$$ using the chain rule we get
$$\frac{1}{y}y'=-\frac{1}{x^2}\ln(\cos(x))+\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{-\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)$$

Comment: Can you proceed now?

Comment: It's clear, but just to dot i's and cross t's: your solution assumes that the OP meant for $y = (\cos x)^{1/x}$.

Comment: @peter a g Just $f(x)^a=(f(x))^a$ instead $f\left(x^a\right).$ ;)

Comment: Every CAS use the notation $$\cos(x)^2=(\cos(x))^2$$

Comment: But $$\cos(x^2)$$ is another thing.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg -and Dr. SG! I know - I agree!  Of course! My comment was for the benefit of the OP...

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thank you very much. Is this what is expected? $y^{'}=\dfrac {-x\ln \left( \cos \left( x\right) \right) \times \sin \left( x\right) }{x^{2}\cos \left( x\right) } \cos \left( x\right)$